# Android app crashing when long click text in edittext

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a dialog fragment with editable text. When you long press on the text it crashes the app. Not sure why this has suddenly started happening as it used to work fine but now crashes consistently, and not too sure where to look as logcat seems to imply it's trying to inflate a view for a long click.

Here's the simple dialog fragment creation (MobileAlertDialog inherits from DialogFragment with a few defaults set)

```
var alertDialog = new Widgets.MobileAlertDialogFragment();
            alertDialog.Title = s.Name;
            EditText input = new EditText(this);
            (input as EditText).Text = s.Value;
            alertDialog.MessageView = input;
            alertDialog.PositiveCallback = () =>
            {
              s.Value = input.Text;
              RefreshSettings();
            };
            alertDialog.CancelCallback = () =>
            {
              //Do nothing...
            };
            alertDialog.Show(this.SupportFragmentManager, "ENTER_VALUE_DIALOG");
```

And here's the logcat:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main

07-20 11:55:10.459 D/AndroidRuntime( 4886): Shutting down VM

07-20 11:55:10.459 W/dalvikvm( 4886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fe8930)

--------- beginning of /dev/log/system

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.initForMode(ActionBarContextView.java:206)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2305)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2243)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:623)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:623)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:623)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:623)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:623)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4302)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1517)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:839)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8066)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17351)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     ... 28 more

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=24; index=2231

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:124)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:928)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:578)

07-20 11:55:10.467 E/AndroidRuntime( 4886):     ... 31 more

07-20 11:55:10.475 W/ActivityManager(  459):   Force finishing activity AndroidApp/AndroidBase.SettingsView

07-20 11:55:10.998 W/ActivityManager(  459): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4294d660 u0 AndroidApp/AndroidBase.SettingsView}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved our issue thanks to answer by Loures here: [Inflate Exception on setting up a long click event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083744/inflate-exception-on-setting-up-a-long-click-event-listener/24452760#24452760)

Basically as part of rebranding app some styles got android:fontFamily items added. Weird thing was this only caused long-click crashing for nexus7 tablets, continued to work fine on Samsung Galaxy Tab, OnePlus One etc.